Is the following formula for power of bivariate regression correct?
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/643568/261208 quotes the following power formula for multiple linear regression from Vittinghoff (2012):
$$ \gamma=1-\Phi\left[z_{1-\alpha / 2}-\left|\beta_j^a\right| \sigma_{x_j} \sqrt{n\left(1-\rho_j^2\right)} / \sigma_{y \mid \mathbf{x}}\right]$$
In the bivariate case, if I understand what $\sigma_{y \mid \mathbf{x}}$ is correctly, the formula reduces to
$$ \gamma=1-\Phi\left[z_{1-\alpha / 2}-\left|r\right|\sqrt{n}/(1-r^2)\right]$$
For small r (where $\sigma_{y \mid \mathbf{x}} \approx\sigma_y$), this reduces to
$$ \gamma=1-\Phi\left[z_{1-\alpha / 2}-\left|r\right| \sqrt{n}\right]$$
which looks consistent with Fisher r-to-z (albeit w/o checking details carefully).
Is the large-r formula I gave also correct?
Edit: I'm not planning to use the bivariate formula; I'm just trying to understand how this all fits together.
